# Did chrome change its cookies database location to Network folder

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

While looking for the Cookies database in chrome profile I didn't find it under the Default folder so I searched for it and found it in a subfolder named Network. My chrome version is 96 and it was in the Default folder before so did chrome change its cookies path recently ?

Comment: the chrome profile storage is an internal implementation detail

Comment: @DanielA.White I know but I'm asking to see did it change for other users too or not

Comment: I'm using 97.0.4692.71 on W10 and for me it's also under "...\User Data\Default\Network".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## YES

Google chrome cookies now are located in `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Network\Cookies`